# Mysql join query

Tags: mysql, sql

Im sure there's a simple solution to this but I can't figure it out at all.

I have a table of photos that have states and countries associated with them.
I have two simple queries, one to get the number of photos per country:

```
select country, count(*) from photos group by country;

+-------------+----------+
| country     | count(*) |
+-------------+----------+
| Argentina   |        6 |
| Australia   |        5 |
| Chile       |        3 |
| Ecuador     |       10 |
| France      |        1 |
| Hong Kong   |        4 |
| Indonesia   |        6 |
| Ireland     |       16 |
| Malaysia    |        1 |
| New Zealand |        3 |
| Peru        |        8 |
+-------------+----------+
```

The other gets the number of photos per state (and country):

```
select country, state, count(*) from photos group by country, state;

+-------------+---------------------+----------+
| country     | state               | count(*) |
+-------------+---------------------+----------+
| Argentina   | Misiones            |        2 |
| Argentina   | Salta               |        4 |
| Australia   | New South Wales     |        1 |
| Australia   | Victoria            |        4 |
| Chile       | Antofagasta         |        3 |
| Ecuador     | Galapagos           |        5 |
| Ecuador     | Sucumbios           |        5 |
| France      | Aquitaine           |        1 |
| Hong Kong   | Hong Kong           |        4 |
| Indonesia   | Bali                |        3 |
| Indonesia   | Nusa Tenggara Barat |        1 |
| Indonesia   | Yogyakarta          |        2 |
| Ireland     | Antrim              |        1 |
| Ireland     | Cork                |        1 |
| Ireland     | Derry               |        2 |
| Ireland     | Donegal             |        8 |
| Ireland     | Kerry               |        1 |
| Ireland     | Sligo               |        1 |
| Ireland     | Waterford           |        1 |
| Ireland     | Wexford             |        1 |
| Malaysia    | Sabah               |        1 |
| New Zealand | Manawatu            |        2 |
| New Zealand | Westland            |        1 |
| Peru        | Cusco               |        6 |
| Peru        | La Libertad         |        2 |
+-------------+---------------------+----------+
```

What I'd like to do is to perform a join on these queries that results in the following:

```
+-------------+---------------------+----------+----------+
| country     | state               |   statet | countryt |
+-------------+---------------------+----------+----------+
| Argentina   | Misiones            |        2 |        6 |
| Argentina   | Salta               |        4 |        6 |
| Australia   | New South Wales     |        1 |        5 |
| Australia   | Victoria            |        4 |        5 |
| Chile       | Antofagasta         |        3 |        3 |
| Ecuador     | Galapagos           |        5 |       10 |
| Ecuador     | Sucumbios           |        5 |       10 |
| France      | Aquitaine           |        1 |        1 |
| Hong Kong   | Hong Kong           |        4 |        4 |
| Indonesia   | Bali                |        3 |        6 |
| Indonesia   | Nusa Tenggara Barat |        1 |        6 |
| Indonesia   | Yogyakarta          |        2 |        6 |
| Ireland     | Antrim              |        1 |       16 |
| Ireland     | Cork                |        1 |       16 |
| Ireland     | Derry               |        2 |       16 |
| Ireland     | Donegal             |        8 |       16 |
| Ireland     | Kerry               |        1 |       16 |
| Ireland     | Sligo               |        1 |       16 |
| Ireland     | Waterford           |        1 |       16 |
| Ireland     | Wexford             |        1 |       16 |
| Malaysia    | Sabah               |        1 |        1 |
| New Zealand | Manawatu            |        2 |        3 |
| New Zealand | Westland            |        1 |        3 |
| Peru        | Cusco               |        6 |        8 |
| Peru        | La Libertad         |        2 |        8 |
+-------------+---------------------+----------+----------+
```

I've been playing around with joins all morning and can't figure it out, any pointers would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd go subquery:

```
select 
     country, 
     state, 
     count(*) as state, 
     (select count(*) from photos inr 
          where inr.country = otr.country) 
from photos otr group by country, state;
```

Comment: WHERE needs to replace HAVING in the subquery.

Answer (score 1):

Does it work as you expecting?

```
 SELECT country, state, COUNT(DISTINCT country), COUNT(state)
  FROM photos 
  GROUP BY country, state
```

Also, try to remove DISTINCT keyword if you need to count the same country per different states

Comment: May be, it returns COUNTRY - STATE - NUMBER_OF_COUNTRIES - NUMBER_OF_STATE_PER_COUNTRY, also by removing DISTING country you may get more expanded view

Comment: this will always return 1 for country, because every records in `country-state` is always having same country

Comment: Absolutely, and for me it makes more sense rather than return for the unique country name COUNT more thatn 1 ;) But if question author want to see count of unique pairs - then DISTINCT should be removed

Answer (score 1):

```
select cs.country, cs.state, count(*) as statet, c.countryt
from photos cs
left join (select country, count(*) countryt from photos group by country) as c
on c.country=cs.country
group by cs.country, cs.state;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
SELECT country_state.country, country_state.state, 
       country_state.statet, country.countryt
FROM
(SELECT country, count(*) as countryt FROM photos group by country) AS country
JOIN
(SELECT country, state, count(*) as statet FROM photos group by country, state) AS country_state ON country.country = country_state.country
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
select * 
from (
    select country, state, count(*) from photos group by country, state
) a
inner join (
    select country, count(*) from photos group by country
) b on a.country = b.country
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution, tested and should give the exact result:

```
SELECT a.country AS country, p.state AS state, COUNT(*) AS statet, a.count AS countryt 
FROM ( SELECT p1.country, COUNT(*) AS count FROM photos p1 GROUP BY p1.country) a 
JOIN photos p ON (p.country = a.country) 
GROUP BY p.state;
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

To avoid having to query your table twice, you could use analytics.

```
select country
  , state
  ,group_by_country
  ,group_by_state
from (select country
       , state
       , count(*) over  (partition by country) group_by_country
       , count(*) over  (partition by country,state) group_by_state
       ,row_number() over (partition by country,state order by country,state) row_num
  from photos
  order by country,state)
where row_num = 1;
```